# Deflate numbers by price index (CPI), when there are varying observation numbers for each year

Tags: r, dplyr, economics

I have some Revenue data in a format like that shown below. So the years are not sequential and they can also repeat (because of a different firm).

> ```
>   Firm Year Revenue
> 1    A 2018     100
> 2    B 2017      90
> 3    B 2018      80
> 4    C 2016      20
> ```

And I want to adjust the Revenue for inflation, by dividing through by the appropriate CPI for each year. The CPI data looks like this:

> ```
>   Year CPI
> 1 2016  98
> 2 2017 100
> 3 2018 101
> ```

I have a solution that works, but is this the best way to do it? Is it clumsy to `mutate` an entire calculating column in there?

```
revenue <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                      Firm = c("A", "B", "B", "C"),
                      Year = c(2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L),
                      Revenue = c(100L, 90L, 80L, 20L)
)

cpi <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L),
  CPI = c(98L, 100L, 101L)
)


library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(revenue, cpi, by = 'Year')
mutate(df, real_revenue = (Revenue*100)/CPI)
```

The output is correct, shown below. But is this the best way to do it?

> ```
>   Firm Year Revenue CPI real_revenue
> 1    A 2018     100 101     99.00990
> 2    B 2017      90 100     90.00000
> 3    B 2018      80 101     79.20792
> 4    C 2016      20  98     20.40816
> ```

Comment: I don't see a problem?

Comment: If you are looking for an efficient approach, `library(data.table);setDT(revenue)[cpi, real_revenue := (Revenue * 100)/CPI, on = .(Year)]`

Comment: Using your real data, to avoid matching only by Year, you would simply match by multiple variables, e.g. `left_join(revenue, cpi, by = c("Year" = "Year", "Firm" = "Firm"))`.